# Alternatives to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, cloud

I want to create a REST Node application which can talk to Microsoft Office 365 and fetch me back my calendar information in the form of JSON. I am using https://github.com/jasonjoh/node-calendar-sync as the base code.

When I tried deploying this app to Heroku, I get the following error

```
2017-02-18T20:04:04.472725+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sleepy-depths-93877.herokuapp.com request_id=b2fc89a1-5493-417d-9ee9-c81dd85d17fd fwd="157.49.2.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-18T20:04:10.593603+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sleepy-depths-93877.herokuapp.com request_id=92860d21-8d13-4e6a-8cf7-d2580e88a7a4 fwd="157.49.2.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I am unable to resolve this error.

I have the following questions:

1. Is it not possible to deploy a Node app as given in the link for Free?
2. Are there any other ways of deploying the app to cloud?

With regards

Comment: It's definitely possible to deploy a nodejs app to Heroku.  If I were you I would go through your config files and logs with a fine toothed comb.  Unfortunately, it's been years since I've actually set up an app on Heroku so I don't have specific advice off-hand.  You could use some other hosting service if you have more experience with setting it up on a linux box (AWS is a breeze on EC2) or you could try Google App Engine for a different experience that is more like the managed instances of Heroku.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to deploy your app to the web. Here is a list of just a few in no particular order:

- [Digital oceans](https://www.digitalocean.com/). It may be a little pricey, but it has great service and huge student benefits. Its docs are also **AMAZING!**
- [Port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding). This is free (depending on your internet provider) but it can take up a lot of your bandwidth depending on how many people are on your website. You also need a spare computer to host it on.
- [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_US&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=cloud_computing_b&sc_content=aws_core_e_control_q32016&sc_detail=a.w.s&sc_category=cloud_computing&sc_segment=102882727002&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=US&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!102882727002!e!!g!!a.w.s&ef_id=WJ1ExAAAAC-FFj4a:20170218210507:s). They have a super long free trial, and are great for big projects.
- [Open shift.](https://www.openshift.com/) This is quite possibly the best of them all, especially for small projects. You can host up to 3 different apps without spending a penny.

After you select your server hosting company, what you will do is [ssh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) into the server, and run your code like you would on your personal computer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have some questions:

1. Can we use Open Shift from Windows?
2. What about Microsoft Azure?

Comment: Yes, any of these will work form any OS

Comment: That will work too. I personally don't like it as much, but it will work. The reason that I did not put it on my list is there is nothing special about it. digital oceans has good student benefits and great docs. Port forwarding is a good options that you don't always hear about, open shift gives you a lot of free stuff. AWS also does not have that much special about it, but it has better pricing for really big stuff.